# importing via Pandas CSV into Django model manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django, pandas

Total newbie to Django. I decided to put my hand up at work to develop a small POC app but cannot seem to get past importing csv data via Pandas into my Django model manytomanyField. Everything else is working except for the m2m field.

Here is a portion of my model:

```
class Service_Interval(models.Model):
    interval_name = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)

class Task(models.Model):
    service_intervals = models.ManyToManyField(Service_Interval, related_name="intervals")
```

Here is my View:

```
def Import_Excel_pandas(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:      
        myfile = request. FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)              
        #exceldata = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col ="Requirements")              
        df=pd.read_csv('sheets/import_csv/'+filename, sep=',', usecols=['ID','Requirements','Service Intervals','Task Created'])
            #print(df)
        row_iter = df.iterrows() 
        objs = [
            Task(
                id = row['ID'],
                requirements = row['Requirements'],
                task_created = row['Task Created'],
                #service_intervals = row['Service Intervals'], << - dont work.                                                     
            )                                              
            for index, row in row_iter
        ]
        Task.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

Here in some of the CSV:

[image]

I think I need to connect to connect/create in Service_Interval first then add to Tasks inside the loop somewhere, but I'm stuck on how/where to add the code within the object task and if the process is correct. Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a while now.

```
                   intervals = row['Service Intervals']
                    service_intervals = ast.literal_eval(intervals)
                    service_intervals = map(str.lower, service_intervals)
                    service_intervals = list(set(service_intervals))
                    for interval_name in service_intervals:
                            service_intervals, _ =                             Service_Interval.objects.get_or_create(name=interval_name)
                            Task.service_intervals.add(service_intervals)
```

Comment: Welcome. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) holds for csv sample as well. Please post it as text instead.